# SSRS reportviewer refreshes w/o View Report

Tags: parameters, refresh, reportviewer

I am displaying SSRS report in .net web app using reportviewer 9
I have three parameters (code below)
I dont want to pass any parameters programmatically
basically I want reportviewer display report with params and then select whatever 
params and press View Report each time i.e. simple no interaction with web page.

What happens is it does display parameter area with first parameter dropdown enabled
but when I select some value and click on second dropdown it all refreshes report retrieved with defaults and all dropdowns set to defaults again!

It does not let me in orderly fashion to select 3 parameter dropdowns one after another and then click on View report

---

```
viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials =
        new MyReportServerCredentials();
viewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote; //work on report resides in the server not local
viewer.ShowFindControls = true;
viewer.ShowRefreshButton = true;
viewer.ShowExportControls = true;
viewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true; //hide parameters area and we will pass it through our controls
viewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
//viewer.ServerReport.
viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportingServiceUrl"]); //Report Server URL not Report Server Manager URL
viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = report.Path;
viewer.ServerReport.Refresh(); //display the report
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing values is a postback, you should wrap your code above so that it only occurs if not posting back.

Comment: ek_ny thanks it did! Ajax controls sometimes makes you forget postback

Comment: Thanks much-- appreciate it. MVC really starts making you forget it. :)